# I can't see anything I am installing, can't find installed programs

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04, deb

I have installed a lot of debs and programs through apt get... it says i have these programs but I can't see them anywhere, what's going on? It says it's there... but where?[image]

Edit: The problem may have been not restarting?

Comment: Press the Super key on your keyboard, also known as the Windows key. Type a few letters of the app you are looking for. After you have started an app you can right click its icon in the launch panel and choose "Add to favourites".

Comment: yeah exactly Jos, I can't see any programs, none of them show up, no programs, installed, but do not show up, not anywhere

Comment: There was a faulty Gnome extension a while ago - I believe it was the Appfolders Management extension - that caused all icons to disappear from that page. Go to extensions.gnome.org and disable that, if you have it enabled.

Comment: there are icons, just not for any of the programs I have installed, so it can't be the same bug?

Comment: Your "I can't see any programs, none of them show up, no programs, installed, but do not show up, not anywhere" suggested that there were no icons at all.

Comment: but the first sentence adds the context that i am talking about the programs i have been installing through debs?

Comment: "*...and 9 not upgraded*" Fix that first: `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: Which `.deb` packages did you install *exactly*? Did you reboot at least once after installing those packages?

Comment: i can't upgrade now because the snaps filled up my root with bloat again, I'm just going to do a clean install and start from scratch, if i don't put root in a separate partition at least snaps won't be able to stop me writing to the drive to fix the problems they cause

Comment: pomsky, libreoffice, vlc, gimp, anyway don't worry i am just going to reinstall the OS

Comment: If you don't want snaps, just uninstall `snapd` like this: `sudo apt purge snapd`

Comment: i tried that already, it didn't work

Comment: everything's working now with a clean install (and without a separate root partition because it kept backing me into a corner by filling up and making it impossible to make any changes to the system)

Comment: @Rabbit Were you using the snapshot backup tool `snapper`? Snapshots will fill up your disk if you don't periodically delete the old ones. I've never used `snapper` but many other snapshot tools are set to automatically take a snapshot each time you install or uninstall stuff using `apt`. Snapshots are nice to have but they will leave you with no storage space if you're not careful.

Comment: nope, just using the default stuff, good to know though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes installed packages won't show up on your desktop until you log out and log back in.

**Log out and back in or reboot to refresh your desktop.**

---

Now, to list all installed applications, you can run `dpkg` with the `-l` or `--list` option:

```
dpkg -l
```

To narrow down the results, you can pipe `dpkg` to `grep` to search for a keyword like this:

```
dpkg -l | grep libreoffice
```

**and you can use the** `which` **command to find out where the** `libreoffice` **command is installed**:

```
which libreoffice
```

---

If you don't know the exact command to use, but you do know the first few letters of the command, like `libre` for example, you can press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to automatically finish the command for you. This feature is called "tab completion". If more than one command matches, a list of matching commands will print in the terminal after you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> two times.

---

**Also, to list the location of all files installed for a package, you can use the** `-L` **or** `--listfiles` **option like in this example**:

```
dpkg -L vlc
```

Commands are usually installed under a `bin` directory but you don't need to know the location of the command file to run the command, you just need to know the name.

---

Additionally, if you don't want to keep the terminal open after you run a command, you can use an ampersand after the command like this:

```
vlc &
```

and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> a couple of times. If you see some output in the terminal, you can ignore it.

---

Finally, here are some similar commands.

First:

```
apt list
```

will list all installable packages.

```
apt --installed list
```

will list all installed packages.

The following example will search for and list available packages related to the search term `gimp`. Again, use `grep` to narrow down the results if you need to.

```
apt-cache search gimp
```

Similarly,

```
apt search gimp
```

will do almost the same thing.

Also,

```
apt show gimp
```

will show details about the package.

Comment: I think you solved it! I'd say i needed to log out or restart. Thank you